# style in body message in sendmail php

Tags: php, html

In the sendmail php i create table n if we fill & click submit button, mail will receive successfully. I try some example code that i shown below but it will print that all html code except that quotes. Now i want to add some styles like tables or bold italic or add images in body of that mail that is "$message" area... can anyone help ?

```
<?php
ob_start();
$to = "me@mymail.com";
$subject = "Request mail";

$message = "<html><body>";
$message .= '<img src="Images/Logos/Logo_color.png" alt="Logo" />';
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" .$Name.PHP_EOL. "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Company Name:</strong> </td><td>" .$Company.PHP_EOL. "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Mobil Number:</strong> </td><td>" .$Mobile.PHP_EOL. "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email Id:</strong> </td><td>" .$Email.PHP_EOL. "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Address):</strong> </td><td>" .$Address.PHP_EOL. "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>State:</strong> </td><td>" .$State.PHP_EOL. "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Edition:</strong> </td><td>" .$Edition."</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";

$from = "mail@yourdomain.co.in";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
header('Location: http://yourdomain.co.in') ;
?>
```

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: you should add message headers also to your message body like From: To: and then two CRLF

Comment: i need to add tables or make my text in bold or italic... @RiggsFolly

Comment: sorry i cont get can u send me example code @DevZer0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add this line in you code :

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Answer (score 3):

From the [PHP mail function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From:" . $from;
```